# "Error 0x80070005: Failed to launch clean room process" while installing .Net Core SDK 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.1

My Visual Studio 2017 Professional stopped being able to load some projects in a solution, and on investigation, VS tells me that I have to install the ASP.NET and Web development feature. I'm sure that this is already installed (I have built this solution many times), but oh, well, I decided to click Install and re-install what VS claimed to be missing.

The VS 2017 Installer window displays and starts attempting to install .Net Core SDK 2.1. For some reason this silently fails. So I downloaded the executable dotnet-sdk-2.1.101-win-x64.exe and try to Run this as Administrator. This appears to start and then stops. Checking its log (C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Setup_20180322072534_Failed.txt), I can see the following error:

> [1330:15A4][2018-03-22T07:25:34]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to launch clean room process: "C:\Windows\Temp{6B5E7797-D824-4BF0-9B51-A0375BFCE6F3}.cr\dotnet-sdk-2.1.102-win-x64.exe" -burn.clean.room="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.6.27428.2011,chip=x64\dotnet-sdk-2.1.102-win-x64.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=212 -burn.filehandle.self=220 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional" /log "C:\Users\Administrator.DODSON\AppData\Local\Temp\2\dd_setup_20180322072448_001_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log" /quiet /norestart

I googled around for this error, and tried a couple of suggestions:

1. Changed the permissions on the C:\Windows\Temp so that Everyone has full control
2. Repaired the VC 2017 Redistributables
3. Updated Permissions on some registry keys relating to VC 2017 Minimum (I forget the exact name of the keys)

Nothing has worked, and I seem to be stuck. I don't seem to be able to install the ASP.NET and Web development feature without the .Net Core SD. Has anyone seen or solved this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone runs into the same issue, I will post my solution. Essentially, I reset the permissions on the C:\Windows\Temp directory to allow Everyone full control permissions, and then manually re-ran the dotnet-sdk-2.1.101-win-x64.exe installer again as Administrator. This time it succeeded in installing the .Net Core SDK. I then ran the Visual Studio Installer again to re-install the ASP.NET and Web development feature, and now everything is working again.